# Trouble creating bubble sort method to be used with an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, bubble-sort

Trying to create a movie manager for my java 1 class and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the bubble sort method to work with an arraylist. the arraylist contains the elements of `(String name, String genre, String actor, int year)` and I want to be able to sort it by whichever element I desire. I used a switch statement to prompt for what the user wants to sort it by then I was going to use an overloaded method to search depending on which element I sent it.

I tried looking up a bunch of similar code online and using what worked for them but I keep having an issue and I'm not entirely sure where. actually, I think I have a couple of things wrong but I'm not sure how to fix them.

```
public void bubbleSort(ArrayList movieList)
{
    movieList temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < movieList.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < (movieList.size() - i); j++)
        {
                if (this.movieList.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(i - 1)) > 0)
                {
//                  System.out.println("Movie found : %s%n", this.movieList);
                    temp = movieList.get(i);
                    movieList.set(i, movieList.indexOf(i-1));
                    movieList.indexOf(i-1) = temp;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

I just need the method sort the array which I will then display back to the user (I already can display it back).

*EDIT
heres the full code that I have so far

MovieManager class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MovieManager {
    static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //        Movie movie = new Movie();
        Driven drivenClass = new Driven();
        drivenClass.fillArray();
        boolean kill = false;
        while (!kill) //!lose validation boolean?
        {
            System.out.printf("Customer or Employee? %n1: Customer %n2: Employee %nQ: Quit %n");

            switch (stdin.next())       //switch to determine if user is customer or employee.
            {
                case "1": //Customer
                    //copy and edit employee menu
                    break;
                case "2": //Employee
                    System.out.println("Enter password to continue or anything else to go back.");
                    while (stdin.next().equals("123456"))
                    {
                        boolean quit = false;
                        while (!quit)       //loop to allow sequential actions
                        {
                            System.out.printf("What would you like to do? %n1: Display %n2: Sort %n3: Search %n4: Add %n5: Remove %nQ: Quit %n");
                            switch (stdin.next())
                            {
                                case "1": //display
                                    drivenClass.displayMovies();
                                    //add display by type
                                    break;
                                case "2": //sort
                                    drivenClass.sortMovies();
                                    break;
                                case "3": //search
                                    drivenClass.searchMovies();
                                    break;
                                case "4": //add
                                    drivenClass.addMovies();
                                    break;
                                case "5": //remove
                                    drivenClass.removeMovies();
                                    break;
                                case "q":
                                    quit = true;
                                    break;
                                case "Q":
                                    quit = true;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.out.println("Must be a number 1-5");
//                                    stdin.next();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "q": //quit
                    kill = true;
                    break;
                case "Q": //quit
                    kill = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Must enter a 1, 2, or Q.");
                    stdin.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Driven class (has some stuff I used while trying to figure it out commented out so just ignore it)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Driven {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    public ArrayList<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void fillArray()     //method to populate ArrayList initially
    {
        movieList.add(new Movie("Kill All Humans", "Sci-fi", "Robot Assassin", 2138));
        movieList.add(new Movie("42", "Sci-fi", "Life, the universe, and everything", 5462));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Bloody Billy 17 -Yet Another Bloodfest", "Action", "B. J. Blackowitz", 1990));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Always Watching", "Documentary", "Big Brother", 1984));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Robot Samurai", "Kids", "Deus Ex Machina", 2012));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Giant Nuclear Frogs from the South", "Suspense", "Chuck Norris", 1998));
        movieList.add(new Movie("How to Make Cyanide from Apple Seeds", "Educational", "Adolf Hitler", 1940));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Two Birds with No Stones", "Martial-Arts", "Bruce Lee, Tim Cook, Edward Snowden", 1969));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Slow Internet!!!", "Suspense", "Sarah Connar, Linus Torvalds", 2004));
        movieList.add(new Movie("I Know Kung Fu", "Romance", "Steven Seagal, Jackie Chan", 2007));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Space Voyage", "Sci-fi", "Kirk, Spock", 1967));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Pointless Slaughter", "Thriller", "Stephen Hawking, Mike Tyson", 1999));
        movieList.add(new Movie("50 Shades of Death 2: Death before Diplomacy", "Thriller", "Donald Trump, Barrack Obama, Lots of Guns", 2023));
        movieList.add(new Movie("MTV (Music Television) - The Movie", "Action", "Bob Ross", 2010));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Spinach Sailor", "Documentary", "Popeye, Einstein", 1949));
        movieList.add(new Movie("Applegeddon - End of Humanity", "Documentary", "Steve Jobs, Steve Wozniak", 2099));
    }
    public void addMovies()     //method to add movies to full list
    { //!when adding 2 in a row it automatically puts a empty name
        System.out.println("Input movie name:");
        String names = stdin.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input movie genre:");
        String genre = stdin.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input movie actors/actresses:");
        String actor = stdin.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input movie year:");
        while (!stdin.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("Must be a whole number");
            stdin.next();
        }
        int year = stdin.nextInt();
        movieList.add(new Movie(names, genre, actor, year));
        System.out.println("Movie added.");
    }
    public void removeMovies()      //method to delete movies from full list
    { //! add way to quit if chosen by accident
        System.out.println("Enter name of movie to remove.");
        String search = stdin.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < movieList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (movieList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(search))
            {
                System.out.printf("Remove this movie Y/N. %nName: %s %nGenre: %s %nActor: %s %nYear: %s %n %n", movieList.get(i).getName(), movieList.get(i).getGenre(), movieList.get(i).getActor(), movieList.get(i).getYear());
                if (stdin.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {
                    movieList.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("Movie removed.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void displayMovies()     //method to output the full list
    {
        for (Movie movie : movieList)
        {
            System.out.printf("Name: %s %nGenre: %s %nActor: %s %nYear: %s %n %n", movie.getName(), movie.getGenre(), movie.getActor(), movie.getYear());
        }
    }
    public void sortMovies()
    {
        System.out.printf("Sort by: %n1: Title %n2: Genre %n3: Actor/actress %n4: Year %n");
        boolean validChoice = false;
        while (!validChoice)
        {
            switch (stdin.next())
            {
                case "1": //sort by title
                    System.out.println("Enter sort method. 1 for bubble sort. 2 for selection sort.");
//                    displayMovies();
                    bubbleSort(movieList);
//                    Collections.sort(movieList, new Comparator<Movie>() {
//                        @Override
//                        public int compare(Movie o1, Movie o2) {
//                            return 0;
//                        }
//                    });
//                  movieList.get().getName().sort();
//                  movieList.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
//                  System.out.println("sorted");
//                  displayMovies();
//                  movieList.sort(movieList.get(i).getName());
//                  Collections.sort(movieList.get().getName());
                    validChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "2": //sort by genre
                    System.out.println("Enter sort method. 1 for bubble sort. 2 for selection sort.");
                    validChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "3": //sort by actor
                    System.out.println("Enter sort method. 1 for bubble sort. 2 for selection sort.");
                    validChoice = true;
                    break;
                case "4": //sort by year
                    System.out.println("Enter sort method. 1 for bubble sort. 2 for selection sort.");
                    validChoice = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    validChoice = false;
                    System.out.println("Must enter 1-4");
                    stdin.next();
            }
        }
    }

    public void searchMovies()      //method to search for specific movie name
    { //!make it so spacing doesnt matter
        System.out.println("Enter name of movie to find.");
        String search = stdin.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < movieList.size(); i++) {
            if (movieList.get(i).getName().matches(search)) {
                System.out.printf("%s.%nName: %s %nGenre: %s %nActor: %s %nYear: %s %n %n", i+1, movieList.get(i).getName(), movieList.get(i).getGenre(), movieList.get(i).getActor(), movieList.get(i).getYear());
            }
        }
    }
//    public ArrayList setmovieList()
//    {
//        this.movieList = movieList;
//    }
    public ArrayList getmovieList()
    {
        return movieList;
    }
    private ArrayList bubbleSort()
    {
        getmovieList();
        Movie temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < movieList.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < (movieList.get() - i); j++)
            {
                Movie jMovie = movieList.get(j).getMovie();
//                String compareLists = movieList.get(i-1).getName().toLowerCase();
//                System.out.println(compareLists);
                if (movieList.get(i).(movieList.get(i - 1).getName()) < 0)
//                    if (movieList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().matches(compareLists))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Movie found ");
                        temp = movieList.get(i);
                        movieList.set(i, movieList.get(i-1));
                        movieList.set(i-1, temp);
                    }

            }
        }
    }
//    public ArrayList<Movie> getmovieList()       //!Lose?
//    {
//        return movieList;
//    }

}

//// Java program to demonstrate working of Collections.sort()
//import java.util.*;
//
//public class Collectionsorting
//{
//    public static void main(String[] args)
//    {
//        // Create a list of strings
//        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
//        al.add("Geeks For Geeks");
//        al.add("Friends");
//        al.add("Dear");
//        al.add("Is");
//        al.add("Superb");
//
//      /* Collections.sort method is sorting the
//      elements of ArrayList in ascending order. */
//        Collections.sort(al);
//
//        // Let us print the sorted list
//        System.out.println("List after the use of" +
//                " Collection.sort() :\n" + al);
//    }
//}
```

Movie class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Movie {
    private String name;
    private String genre;
    private String actor;
    private int year;


    public  Movie(String name, String genre, String actor, int year){
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.actor = actor;
        this.year = year;
    }   //movie constructor

//    public Movie() { }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public String getActor()
    {
        return actor;
    }
    public String getGenre()
    {
        return genre;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public Movie getMovie(int i)
    {
        Movie temp = Driven.(getName(), getGenre().indexOf(i), getActor(i), getYear(i));
        return Movie();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just write the three comparators and use Collections.sort?  It seems pointless to write your own sort method when others have already done it better.

Comment: Take a look [at this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/). Besides that: Bubble Sort is a very inefficient sorting alrogithm. Time complexity is quadratic - O(n²) in the worst case.

Comment: @Bakon Jarser What would that look like? it's my school final so I can only use what we learned in class and bubble sort was just one of the sorting methods we were told as one of the 2 we are required to offer the user.

Comment: I think my issue has to do with the fact that im trying to sort an ```ArrayList<>``` composed of the object ```movie```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints. Bubble sort should only require one pass through the list starting at index 1.  Compare it to the index below it.  If compareTo returns < 0 then leave the item where it is. Otherwise swap the two items and then compare it to the item on the left again.  So the second for loop should be counting down towards index 0 and you should break that loop when the compareTo returns >= 0.

You were close on this line but you were comparing to the string version of i - 1 instead of the string in the list at i - 1.

```
if (this.movieList.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(movieList.get(i - 1).getName()) < 0)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback I've been working on this for hours. How exactly should I call on the entire Movie object instead of just the index? I think I might have created the object wrong weird or something (a concept I can review after finals)

Comment: You are getting the entire object when you call get.  You haven't shown all your code but assuming you have a List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>(); then you access the movies like this Movie m = movieList.get(indexOfMoveToAccess);

Comment: I have ```public ArrayList<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();``` and a movie constructor of ```public  Movie(String name, String genre, String actor, int year){
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.actor = actor;
        this.year = year;
    }``` ill upload my full code now for if it helps.